# Should convert 'k' and 't' sounds to 'g' and 'd' sounds when they follow 's' in a word for pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

Should convert 'k' and 't' sounds to 'g' and 'd' sounds when they follow 's' in a word for pronunciation?

For example, stamp is pronounced as 's dæm p', etc.

Comment: Did you check any dictionaries for pronunciation guides?  Have you seen something that suggests that you *should* make this change?

Comment: Could you please explain your question? I do not understand it at all.

Comment: Hi. I have never heard a native English speaker pronounce stamp like that.  Where did you get this information?

Comment: Perhaps the best thing would be to listen to the way that native English speakers pronounce words, and then pronounce them the same way.

Comment: @TannerSwett If you're on ELL, surely you know that phonemes sound different to people depending on their L1. Confusing unaspirated /t/ for /d/ is not that ridiculous.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yes, that's a good point. I guess my point is that if you're thinking of two possible pronunciations, and one of them sounds similar to the way that native speakers speak, and the other one does not, then you should probably use the pronunciation that sounds similar to the native speakers. Then again, I admit that even that's not an absolute rule, since things that sound different to natives often sound similar to learners, and vice versa.

Comment: @TannerSwett But that's what Xuesong is asking for? It's just a rude and not very useful comment to make

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Indeed, mistaking it for the voiced alternative is very plausible. (Had OP not used IPA in the question I might have decided it wasn't worth an answer pointing out that at the technical level this is wrong and it should indeed be voiceless.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak I am not sure they meant to use IPA, ash is sometimes used in non-IPA transcriptions as well.

Comment: Midwest, *stamp* is the same pronunciation as *can't*. "listen to the way that native English speakers pronounce words, and then pronounce them the same way." - unless they're British and they *caaunt* say *can't* right and pronounce *stamp* with one and a half *u*'s.

Comment: It has occurred to me that there can be big differences between what people can hear and what they can pronounce, and that their perception can be greatly influenced by what they "know" to be right.  Examples: I can hear the difference between Korean 당 and 땅...barely.  No way could I reproduce them consistently correctly.  But to native Korean speakers, they're clearly different.  To my own wife, a native English speaker, *pen* and *pin* will forever be pronounced *and heard* exactly the same.

Answer (score 16):

No. You should pronounce it as an unaspirated [t].

Longer: There are two phenomena in play: aspiration and voice.

| sounds | voiced? | aspirated? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /p t k/ | no | at the start of a syllable |
| /b d g/ | yes | no |

Thus what you hear in a cluster like 'stamp' is the voiceless plosive /t/ without its aspiration. Its voicing does not change.

However, because many languages, probably incl. yours, do not use aspiration, English's use of it is very salient. Thus it's easy to mistake it for the quality that defines /p t k/.

But it isn't. It's secondary from the phonological point of view. The phoneme /t/ has phonetic realizations [t] and [tʰ] (among others); it does not have a phonetic realization [d]. Hence, it's [stæmp], but not [stʰæmp] and not [sdæmp].

---

Incidentally, English native speakers have a similar problem. Take away the aspiration and we think we're perceiving /b d g/. However, it's possible to train yourself to perceive the distinction.

Hence, it might be possible to argue that aspiration *is* the key element and voicing is the second. But even if aspiration is treated as the primary distinction, it doesn't really make sense to target a /d/. A /d/ should be impossible in a cluster after a voiceless /s/ from a phonotactics point of view.

Comment: Moreover the common romanisation of Chinese (Pinyin) uses "d" for "unaspirated unvoiced consonant", which causes all sorts of difficulty for English speakers learning Mandarin.

Comment: Agreed.  Short answer for Xuesong Gao: native English speakers can definitely hear the difference between 's**t**amp' and 's**d**amp', and the second one is wrong.  ['sd' is not an allowed consonant cluster in English.](https://www.sltinfo.com/syllables-and-clusters/#:~:text=There%20are%2C%20therefore%2C%2026%20two,initial%20combinations%20in%20actual%20words.)

Comment: @stangdon Indeed, and one reason we can tell them apart is that there's no reasonable way (for us, anyway) to articulate a /d/ after an /s/, so we have to exaggerate the change in voicing and that makes it more salient than the aspiration change (again, for us).

Comment: @stangdon: More accurately "sd" is not allowed at the *start* of an English word.  It's OK in the middle (di**sd**ain, eave**sd**rop, juri**sd**iction, mi**sd**irect, wi**sd**om), though voicing assimilation means that it's likely actually pronounced [zd] or [st].

Comment: @stangdon I don't think English speakers can definitely hear the difference between s**t**amp and s**d**amp. I think almost all speakers will hear both of these as "stamp", and not even find the **d** one particularly odd

Comment: @dan04 That's not really the same thing, though; in all of the words you list **sd** is across a syllable boundary, whereas in the hypothetical "sdamp" it isn't.

Comment: @sumelic It may not make sense to treat [t] and [d] as separate realizations in that context, but I think it *is* useful to treat /t/ and /d/ as separate phonemes. If OP wants to target [d] phonetically, they can feel free and it will be functionally similar, but as long as they're looking at phonetics they might as well target voicelessness.

Comment: @dan04 "eavesdrop" and "wisdom" have /zd/, not /sd/, despite the spelling

Comment: @theonlygusti The OP's question is about how native speakers ***pronounce*** sounds, not at all about how we ***hear*** them. We do not pronounce "stamp" like /sdamp/.

Comment: I see you engaged already with the video evidence @the-baby-is-you provided. Sorry to have to downvote this. Asking nonnative speakers to emulate a distinction we don't actually make is counterproductive. I hope others will help upvote the other answer for the benefit of learners.

Comment: @gotube Please watch the Geoff Lindsey video and let us know if you stand by that assertion.

https://youtu.be/U37hX8NPgjQ?t=83

Comment: @CynicallyNaive What he needs to do is compare that with 'beach' as well. But e.g. [at 2:55](https://youtu.be/U37hX8NPgjQ?t=175), if you speak a language with unaspirated plosives, you can easily hear the voicelessness of the [p]. In any case, my argument remains the same as I addressed to sumelic above. It simply doesn't make sense to advise a learner to target nonexistent voicing, in the hopes that they'll pick up the attendant deletion of aspiration, rather than just to delete aspiration.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive Thanks for the link. I watched it and still stand by my statement. The visual displays of the sound waves near the beginning of the video show that there is an audible difference between [p] (unreleased) and [b], even if native speakers lump them into the same phoneme when hearing them. And played side by side, they're distinguishable. I'm also a trained Linguist, so I could hear they weren't quite perfect.

Comment: " some people refer to "Daoism" but what they're hearing is "Taoism" without aspiration on the /t/. " Or they could just be hearing [d], which exists as an allophone of [t] for some speakers of Standard Chinese: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4860.

Comment: @sumelic ah, interesting. Deleting from answer.

Comment: To describe /b d g/ as “Voiced: yes” is an oversimplification to the point of being plain wrong. Postvocalically, voicing is the norm; in other positions, voicing is non-distinctive, and anything from complete devoicing through partial voicing is ubiquitous, _but full voicing is quite rare_. The /d/ in _damp_ will almost never be realised as a fully voiced [d]. This also means that in positions that are neither postvocalic nor syllable-initial (i.e., non-initially in clusters), there is no possibility of distinguishing /t/ and /d/, since neither voicing nor aspiration is likely.

Comment: You suggest that the OP's native language doesn't use aspiration. I would say, on the contrary: the fact that the OP notices the difference between aspirated 'tamp' and unaspiratied 'stamp' suggests to me that their native lanuage does maintain such a distinction. (And their user name seems to back me up on this!)

Comment: @TonyK Speakers of languages that don't use aspiration tend to find it very salient. It's not one of the subtler phonetic phenomena. As my French friend said to me when I was learning French with my Anglophone accent, "Why do English speakers always hit the 't' so hard?!"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Phonology vs. phonetics. What it boils down to is that the sound written ⟨t⟩, in a cluster after ⟨s⟩, shouldn't be voiced and can't be represented as [d] in narrow transcription.

Comment: @LukeSawczak It certainly shouldn’t – but nor should the sound written ⟨d⟩ in _damp_, not in narrow transcription. Apart from the unqualified “yes” in the table, I was referring to your last paragraph where you say you shouldn’t target (phonemic) /d/. This does not follow, because a phonemic /d/ does not imply a phonetically voiced [d], and the word-initial realisation of /d/ (≈ [t]) _is_ in fact what you should be targeting. So essentially I’m saying it should not be pronounced [sdæmp], but it should be pronounced /sdæmp/, because /sdæmp/ and /stæmp/ will be phonetically identical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, I see your point. Of course, if they have identical realizations, there's no reason to target /d/ rather than /t/ :) You would say: "Nor vice versa!" and I would say there's no point in bringing /d/ into it at all to conflict with both spelling and intuition.

Comment: (Incidentally, I agree with @TonyK that the asker’s native language is likely Mandarin, which distinguishes aspiration, but not voicing. What Mandarin _doesn’t_ have is consonant clusters or stops anywhere but syllable-initial position, and aspirated stops are always aspirated. To a Mandarin speaker, it is often more intuitive to think of _stamp_ as _sdamp_, because the automatic deaspiration of [tʰ] after the [s] is nonexistent in Mandarin; the intuitive pronunciation of /st/ would be [stʰ], which is impossible in this position in English.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is very interesting indeed. I certainly did assume it was Mandarin but didn't know those features of Mandarin. The fact that it distinguishes aspiration is imo the most interesting and relevant info to come out of the dozens of comments on this question and its answers since it affects the pedagogical target.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**, in fact. English speakers cannot tell the difference between "stamp" and "sdamp" (or "disgust" and "discussed", etc.) in most speech, no matter how much they tell you they can. It's possible to pronounce them so they can be distinguished, but this is not the same thing as doing so by default.

Linguist Geoff Lindsey [demonstrates here](https://youtu.be/U37hX8NPgjQ?t=80) that clipping the /s/ out of an audio clip of the word "speech" makes it indistinguishable from "beach".

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote (and I wish people who did would comment), but I will note that our inability to distinguish between [t] and [d] wouldn't mean one should target /d/. The other language's realizations of /d/ may not actually be the same as our [t]. And as stangdon hinted, if we native speakers in particular *try* to clearly articulate a /d/ after an /s/, it's quite noticeably wrong.

Comment: @LukeSawczak And I'd argue that for non-native speakers, understanding that they're identical 99% of the time is more helpful than trying to hear a difference that doesn't exist. Understanding the fine nuances that occasionally make them different should come second. Thank you for engaging, genuinely.

Comment: I think the issue is with how one defines "native speaker", which Dr Lindsey conflates with "British or American". Native speakers of English in, say, India do not aspirate /p t k/ at all, in any position, and yet readily distinguish them from /b d g/. I spent my early life in India and realized pretty quickly after I moved to the US that I needed to aspirate if my American hearers were to hear my saying /pat/ as "pat" rather than "bat". Yet for me, that's code-switching. When I'm around other native speakers who grew up in India, I switch back to the unaspirated forms. (Contd.)

Comment: As for the examples in Dr Lindsey's video, in each set of examples, there was at least one person whose pronunciation made it abundantly clear to me that this was not (say) beach but peach, or door but store. 

Y'know what, Imma turn this into an answer.

Comment: -1 This points out that native speakers ***hear*** [p] as [b] in the context [pi:tS]. This is not at all the same as saying native English speakers ***pronounce*** [p] as [b] in the word "speech", and *really* doesn't mean that learners should try and pronounce "speech" as [sbi:tS]. This answer is wrong and harmful to learners.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I hear the difference between "stamp" and "sdamp". Of course, if someone said, "I'm going to the post office to buy some sdamps" I might register their pronunciation but I definitely wouldn't think they were saying a different word. On the other hand, if they said something like "it's (a) sdamp" and they had an accent, I might be confused. Did they mean to say "it's damp" or "it's a stamp"?

Comment: Note the question also talks about 'k' turning to 'g' when following an 's'. I would absolutely find it strange for someone to "asg" me a question. I agree this answer is not good advice. Even native English speakers are often asked to clearly enunciate and differentiate these sounds, such as when singing in a chorale. It can only help to learn intentional, differentiated pronunciation, even when many native speakers are not as careful. Native speakers have other advantages in terms of communicating clearly and also don't always communicate clearly.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You're attempting to overgeneralize a phenomenon that occurs only at certain word positions. Though it doesn't have to be word-initial, that's what the OP asked about and what I've addressed.

Comment: @gotube - "...hear [p] as [b] in the context [pi:tS]. This is not at all the same as saying native English speakers pronounce [p] as [b] in the word "speech""

I don't understand your meaning. If native speakers can't hear the difference in how native speakers (at least UK / NAm ones) pronounce the consonant, you're advocating a distinction without a difference. Why would nonnatives try to make distinctions that native listeners won't recognize?

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. Are you thinking the question is *only* about "stamp" or only about situations where the word *starts* with "sk" or "st"? I don’t interpret the question that way at all. Even if we’re only talking about words that start with "sk", I would have a very hard time understanding someone who says "sgit" instead of "skit" or "sgulk" instead of "skulk".

Comment: No. That's not what Geoff tells you, at least it shouldn't be. A native-English speaker will likely tell you that the word *speech* with the [s] cut of the beginning is the word *beach*. However, that's because without the preceding [s], aspiration would be the most important cue for telling /p/ from /b/. There are no contrasting words in English which have /sb/ at the beginning - so it's not possible to "tell them apart." The reality is that the difference between voiced and unvoiced plosives is neutralised in such environments, not that unvoiced plosives become voiced!

Comment: @CynicallyNaive There is an audible difference between [p] and [b]. If we teach learners to use [b] where native speakers use [p] we are teaching them bad pronunciation. The fact that native speakers hear [pi:tS] as the word "beach" in no way demonstrates that native speakers will also hear [sbi:tS] as a natural pronunciation of "speech"....

Comment: @CynicallyNaive ... At the end of Dr. Lindsey's video, he suggests this is the case, but it's a mistake. He doesn't use evidence or reason to come to that conclusion. The "disgust/discussed" issue is better explained by saying both words have two acceptable pronunciations. If both words were truly pronounced the same, it would always be random. The fact that native speakers tend to agree on which is which is evidence that there are two pronunciations, and when the two words are pronounced differently, we choose the [g] one as "disgust" and the [k] one as "discussed".

Comment: @sumelic That makes sense. The letters "b/d/g" in Pinyin represent the pronunciation of the "p/t/k" sounds after "s", but know that the English letters "b/d/g" are not pronounced the same as Pinyin letters "b/d/g". This answer is still wrong and so is it's justification.

Comment: @sumelic I just read your comment on the other answer, "*Mandarin /t/ /p/ /k/ can be phonetically voiced*". This leads me to change my mind back, that no, the Pinyin letters "p/t/k" do not represent the pronunciation of the English letters "p/t/k" after "s" because those Mandarin phonemes are in free variation between voiced and unvoiced, which is not the case with the sounds after "s"

Comment: @sumelic The warning is necessary because the OP isn't the only learner who is going to read this question and see this answer with all the upvotes and nothing to suggest this only applies to Pinyin letters. A good answer is correct on its face so that everybody reading it gets accurate information. The information in this answer is simply false.

Answer (score 9):

**It depends**. To what accent do you, er, aspire?

Native English speakers from, say, India readily distinguish /p t k/ from /b d g/ in all positions of those consonants—even after f or s. That's due to the influence of Indic languages, where aspiration is phonemic. /p/ and /p<sup>h</sup>/ are meaningfully different: e.g., in Hindi, **pal**, पल, *moment*; **phal**, फल, *fruit*. Indeed, /ph/ is not phonemically distinct from /f/ in those languages. The following relations pertain:

| pronunciation | Indian listener | American listener |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [p] | /p/ | /b/ |
| [p<sup>h</sup>] | /f/ | /p/ |

All this can make things a bit bewildering, as when the Indian speaker says "I gave the dog a pat" and the American listener wonders why the speaker gave the canine a flying rodent . Or when an American speaker says "You deserve some pats on the back" and the Indian listener ponders dorsal applications of butter, margarine, olive oil, etc.

To somebody from India, then, even after an s, /p/ is pronounced [p]. Or more precisely, it's pronounced the same way as /p/ is pronounced at the initial position of a morpheme. And that pronunciation is very distinct from [b] to an Indian ear, but not so much to an American one.

Dr Lindsey's [video](https://youtu.be/U37hX8NPgjQ?t=80), referenced in @the-baby-is-you's [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/337088/2143), furnishes a case in point. For each pair of words (door/store, speech/beach) there is at least one speaker whose pronunciation does distinguish the pair clearly enough for my Indian ear. In general, though, he is obviously correct: US/UK pronunciations do not distinguish between /p/ and /b/ (etc.) following s or f. However, while Dr Lindsey conflates "native speaker" with "British or American", there are large numbers of native speakers of English elsewhere in the world. And I do mean *native*, those who grew up speaking the language either exclusively or in true bilingual/multilingual fashion, as opposed learning it as a second, third, or fourth language outside of an immersive context.

So if your native language isn't English, then does your native language give you the ability to hear and reproduce the distinction between [p], [p<sup>h</sup>], and [b]? If so, and if you don't mind having an accent that's somewhat distinctive, by all means reproduce those distinctions. If you cannot consistently hear or reproduce those distinctions, then by all means follow the advice to say "sbeach" or "sgool" for "speech" or "school".

At the end of the day, though, the point is to recognize that even native accents are bewilderingly various. Arguing over whether [p], [p<sup>h</sup>], and [b] are, or ought to be, distinct is about as fruitful as arguing whether [Mary, marry, and merry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3i9rMU8aL-U) are pronounced identically or entirely differently. It all depends: where are you from; how conscious are you of your own accent; to whom are you speaking; and how much do you care that your accent seem neutral to them?

Comment: This is a really interesting point and brings up how Indian English is unfairly marginalized in some discussions. Contextually it's worth remembering that we're talking about < 1M L1 speakers. However that is not a good reason to disregard the importance of Indian English in the development of the language.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive I’d dispute the < 1M figure. It counts only those whose language of family origin is English. It’s true that fewer that 1M Indians speak English with their families of origin. But far more than that, on the order of several million, speak English with native fluency simply because it’s the lingua franca. Bilingualism and multilingualism, where several languages are natively spoken, is a thing. Some U[SK] speakers, being monoglots, assume that the only *true* speakers of English are those who speak no other language fluently, which seriously distorts their linguistic analyses.

Comment: Dr Lindsey’s video is an example, where native == U[SK], and what’s more, only those with a very specific, normative accent.

Comment: It’s useful and interesting knowledge. It is, however, rare for an ESL speaker to intentionally adopt a South Asian accent.

Comment: @Davislor that wasn't the point of my answer. The point is that the OP's question seems to assume that there is one "correct" accent, and that assumption seems unfounded. So what I'm saying to the OP is, don't fret about the correct way to pronounce those words; pronounce them in a way that works for you and your audience. What if the OP does come from a language background that maintains distinctions between [p], [ph], and [b]? Should they intentionally flatten those distinctions? I'd say, not unless they specifically wanted to do so for the sake of their audience.

Comment: @verbose Well, as you say, the OP is implicitly asking about some particular accent. Your answer is very helpful. I think the conclusion, for someone like OP, is, “If you don’t, you’ll sound like someone from India, and Americans might even find you difficult to understand.” They can then make an informed decision.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for the kind words. I don't think, though, that Americans find folks from India hard to understand. Sundar Pichai, Satya Nadella, etc. wouldn't have gotten to where they are if their speech were unintelligible to their co-workers and backers. I find the accent of someone from, say, Kentucky, extremely distinctive, and no doubt that person finds mine equally so. That said, we have no *difficulty* understanding each other. We just think, "this person's pees sound like bees", or "I had no idea *goddamn* was six syllables", and get on with it.

Comment: (contd.) But that's because neither of us cares about sounding "neutral". If OP does care, then yes, OP should take note of Dr Lindsey's observations. Which my answer explicitly says.

Comment: @verbose You seemed to be saying otherwise when you wrote, “All this can make things a bit bewildering, as when the Indian speaker says ‘I gave the dog a pat’ and the American listener wonders why the speaker gave the canine a flying rodent” From personal experience, I usually understand strong South Asian or West African accents, but occasionally mis-hear a word like that.

Comment: @Davislor yeah, well, I was trying to be funny there.   FTR I have never actually misheard an aspirated /p/ for an /f/. I recognize that it *could* happen. And certainly I know that American folks used to mishear my pees as bees when I lacked aspiration, but never to the point of misunderstanding; they just thought I had a weird accent, and the feeling was entirely mutual. I'm trying to reassure the OP that accent doesn't actually matter very much.

Answer (score 2):

Pinyin *g* and *d* are English [unaspirated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant) *k* and *t*.

> one can put a hand or a lit candle in front of one's mouth, and say *spin* [spɪn] and then *pin* [pʰɪn]. One should either feel a puff of air or see a flicker of the candle flame with *pin* that one does not get with *spin*.

In English, *stop* is [stɑp], *top* is [tʰɑp], but *day* is [deɪ̯].

Pinyin *d* is [t], pinyin *t* is [tʰ], so *dao* is [taʊ] and *tao* is [tʰaʊ].

*stamp* should be pronounced as [stæmp] with an unaspirated *t*. That's not the same as English *d* (which normally represents IPA [d]).

The English *d* sound does not exist in Mandarin as far as I know. It is a [voiced consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)), in English the vocal folds begin to vibrate *before* the consonant is released ([voice-onset time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_onset_time)).

In English, the stops *p*, *k*, and *t* are aspirated when they are at the start of a syllable, but not otherwise.

For example, *port* would be [pʰɔɹt], *passport* would still have aspiration [pʰæs.pʰɔɹt], but *sport* should be [spɔɹt] without aspiration.

So, you should only pronounce /t/ as [tʰ] if it is at the start of a syllable. It doesn't matter if it follows an *s* or not.

Comment: Mandarin /t/ /p/ /k/ can be phonetically voiced, there just isn't a contrast between voiceless and voiced versions. See on Linguistics SE: [Does Mandarin Chinese have phonetically voiced plosives, fricatives, or affricates](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4860)

Answer (score 2):

> Should convert 'k' and 't' sounds to 'g' and 'd' sounds when they
> follow 's' in a word for pronunciation?
>
> For example, stamp is pronounced as 's dæm p', etc.

How to answer this question depends on the context.

It's definitely true that the words ***st**amp* and ***sk**in* are not pronounced with the same sounds that the letters T and K make in the words ***t**ank* and ***k**in.* You are right to notice this.

You can use websites like Forvo and Youglish to hear how English speakers pronounce words like ["stamp" (Forvo)](https://forvo.com/word/stamp/#en) (["stamp" Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/stamp/english?)) and ["skin" (Forvo)](https://forvo.com/word/skin/#en) (["skin" Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/skin/english?)).

Imitating this as best as you can should result in an understandable pronunciation.

#### Why you hear a difference, and what that difference is

The phonetic difference is that words like *tank* and *kin* have a puff of air, called "aspiration", at the end of their T and K sounds, while "stamp" and "skin" do not.

This difference isn't represented in English spelling because English words can't start with an S sound followed by an aspirated T or K sound.

It's the same as the difference in Standard Chinese/Mandarin between the sounds written in pinyin with the letters **t p k** (which are aspirated) and the sounds written in pinyin with the letters **d b g** (which are not aspirated). So if you are familiar with that, and that's what you mean by writing 's dæm p', then that's a correct description of the start of English "stamp": the voiceless fricative S followed by an unaspirated voiceless consonant.

However, the letter **d** isn't generally used to represent an unaspirated voiceless consonant in the International Phonetic Alphabet. Instead, in this alphabet, we would mark the difference by transcribing "tank" and "kin" with [tʰ] and [kʰ], where the [ʰ] symbol represents the aspiration of the consonant, vs. "stamp" and "skin" with [st] and [sk] (with no [ʰ]).

The International Phonetic Alphabet prescribes using the letters [b d ɡ] to transcribe what are called "voiced" consonant sounds. These don't appear after word-initial [s] in English, but because they are also unaspirated, some English speakers hear a similarity between them and the voiceless unaspirated [p t k] sounds, as described by the-baby-is-you's answer. (The English phonemes transcribed /b d ɡ/ are not always fully phonetically voiced.) Other English speakers, or speakers of some other languages, may not hear this similarity, meaning for those people, it won't make sense to think of words like *stamp, skin, spin* as starting with *sd-, sg-, sb-* sounds. That's OK: while you can think of these words as starting with *sd-, sd-, sb-* if it helps you avoid using the aspirated  consonant sounds found at the start of "tank", "kin", "pin", there's no requirement for everybody to think of them this way.

And of course, nobody should get the idea that they should pronounce these words with a phonetically voiced [b d ɡ] sound, so for speakers of languages where those sounds contrast with voiceless unaspirated [p t k], such as Italian, it makes the most sense to think of the English consonant clusters as being like their native [sp] [st] [sk].

Answer (score 0):

P, T, and K aspirations are blocked by certain preceding sounds. See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U37hX8NPgjQ for how the sounds change and native English speakers don't even know what sounds we're actually making when speaking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).